# Get rid of delegate method for both Activity and AppCompatActivity by using BaseActivity

Tags: java, android

I am creating a library for handling android permissions [here](https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions).
The library currently needs to have an overridden method in **almost all** of the activities as below:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Permissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(this, requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

But the activities **may not not extend same class** - Some may extends `Activity` and others may extend `AppCompatActivity` (subclass of `Activity` but needs support library).  Some developers may be using AppCompat library and some may not be. I want to include a base class eg PermissionActivity with this method which both type of developers can extend and do not need to override.

Is there any way by which I can include this code inside the library and developers do not need to override it?

Comment: I don't see much wrong with leaving it as is.  You have an overridden `onCreate()` method in all your activities.  If you had more than one line of code, say 10-20 lines, you could extract that code into a shared static method, for example.

Comment: What is the reason that you are using both `Activity` and `AppCompatActivity`? It seems to me that your activities should consistently extend the same super class.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice please check the edited question.

Comment: You still didn't answer my question.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Some developers may be using AppCompat library and some may not be. I want to include a base class eg PermissionActivity which both type of developers can extend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create two new classes, one subclassing `Activity`, one subclassing `AppCompatActivity`. In those two classes, override `onRequestPersissionsResult`.

Then base all of your actual actions on one of the new classes as appropriate.

Comment: actually I am creating a library. Please check the edited question.

Comment: Then you could add one class to your base library and the other to your `AppCompat` library.

Answer (score 4):

When making a library is a good thing to not force the developer to extend some of your classes. This is even a stronger good practice when talking about extending activities since there are lots of libraries that forces you to do that (and therefore forcing you to choose between one or another or making little hacks).

So therefore you should favor **composition** instead of inheritance. You can create some delegate class like this:

```
public class PermissionDelegate {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        ...
    }

    public void onStart() {
        ...
    }

    // Not quite sure if Context is what you need. Check it out
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(Context? context, int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Permissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(context, requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

And delegate all calls from your `Activity` to the delegate:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private PermissionDelegate delegate = new PermissionDelegate();        

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        ...
        delegate.onCreate(savedInstance);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        ...
        delegate.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        delegate.onRequestPermissionsResult(this, requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

And also for `AppCompatActivity`

```
public class MyAppCompatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PermissionDelegate delegate = new PermissionDelegate();        

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        ...
        delegate.onCreate(savedInstance);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        ...
        delegate.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        delegate.onRequestPermissionsResult(this, requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

This way you can offer both **inheritance** option (make your users extend already created classes) and **composition** (add a `PermissionDelegate` in your activities and tie its lifecycle)